# How to translate this curl post of an actual file to python request?

Tags: python, post, curl, python-requests, asana

I have searched stackoverflow thoroughly, but nowhere could I find an answer to this problem.

I'm trying to contribute to asana API [python wrapper](https://github.com/pandemicsyn/asana). The idea is to post a file as an attachment to a task.

In the asana API [docs](http://developer.asana.com/documentation/#attachments), it is specified that the uploaded file "needs to be an actual file, not a stream of bytes."

I have a working curl request like so:

```
curl -u <api_key>: --form "file=@file.txt" https://app.asana.com/api/1.0/tasks/1337/attachments
```

Its working just fine.

I now intend to do the whole thing with [request](http://www.python-requests.org/en/latest/user/quickstart/#post-a-multipart-encoded-file). In the request docs, all they talk about is "upload Multipart-encoded files".

So here's my actual question(s):

1. Does "upload Multipart-encoded files" conflict with file "needs to be an actual file, not a stream of bytes"?
2. How do I properly translate the working curl to a request post?

My go is

```
request.post('https://app.asana.com/api/1.0/tasks/task_id/attachments', auth=(<api_key>, ""), data={'file': open('valid_path_to_file.ext', 'rb')})
```

When running it, I get

```
{"errors":[{"message":"file: File is not an object"}]}
```

from asana.

Comment: I've been able to fix things. The error was in `data={'file': open('valid_path_to_file.ext', 'rb')}`. It should have been `files={'file': open('valid_path_to_file.ext', 'rb')}`. Rather trivial.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can pass a `files` parameter to `requests.post` for form encoded file upload. See example below:

```
import requests

KEY = ''
TASK_ID = ''
url = 'https://app.asana.com/api/1.0/tasks/{0}/attachments'.format(TASK_ID)

with open('file.txt') as f:
    files = {'file': f.read()}
    r = requests.post(url, auth=(KEY, ''), files=files)

print(r.status_code)
print(r.json())
```

Answer (score 0):

This might be exactly the same, but did you try assigning the files parameter outside of the data parameter like on the request website:

```
url = 'http://httpbin.org/post'
files = {'file': open('report.xls', 'rb')}
r = requests.post(url, files=files)
```

http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/user/quickstart/#more-complicated-post-requests

Comment: No, this does not make a difference. In fact, I have it implemented the way you suggest and only 'paraphrased' it for the question.

Comment: Sorry, did not see your answer. But yours should work :)